# BitBucket Jest tests get stuck

Tags: jestjs, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

When pipeline gets to the tests (jest). It just stays there and spinner keeps spinning and nothing happens, no error messages. The test run in local with no errors.
After googling i noticed people suggest to use `--maxWorkers=20%` in jest due to cpu/memory issues. But it didnt help.

Triggering the tests in webpack like this:

```
"test": "jest --coverage --watchAll --maxWorkers=20% --maxConcurrent=2 --verbose --config=configs/jest.json",
```

I have this pipeline setup in bitbucket:

```
image: node:16

pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: Build
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run build
            - npm run test
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to S3
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:1.1.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'eu-west-1'
                S3_BUCKET: 'myname'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'dist'
      - step:
          name: Invalidate CloudFront cache
          trigger: automatic
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-cloudfront-invalidate:0.6.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                DISTRIBUTION_ID: 'E3HTTJFUB2KUCW'
```

Here is the jest config file if it matters.

```
{
  "rootDir": "..",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/tests/__coverage__/",
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/shim.js"
  ],
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src/",
    "<rootDir>/tests/"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|scss|less)$": "<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/"
  ],
  "testRegex": "/tests/.*\\.(ts|tsx)$",
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "DEVELOPMENT": false,
  }
}
```

Comment: How long have you let it run for?

Comment: I let it stay for 20min and still stuck. However i changed the script in webpack to ```"test": "jest  --maxWorkers=20% --maxConcurrent=2 --verbose --config=configs/jest.json``` and now works fine. Not sure if it is correct way.

Answer (score 0):

--watchAll=false should get you out of the menu.